# Apache time stamp incorrect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver

I am using WAMP server running PHP. At a particular step I am trying to capture system time and add it to the database with the following query

```
$strSQLInsert = "UPDATE  track SET  State = 'Repeat' , DateTime = '" . date("m/d/Y h:i:s a") .  "',  where AccID like '". $values['SampleID'] ;
```

but the time stamp is way off than my system time. The date is okay. I googled and found out that I can update my .htaccess with this line

```
SetEnv TZ America/Los_Angles
```

But I couldn't find where htaccess is. How do I get the correct time stamp.

Comment: What about fixing the problem and not the symptoms: The wrong time?

Comment: No I haven't . Where do I create this file? Which folder. c:\wamp\??

Comment: @TimWolla . I don't understand what you mean. My system time is correct. The time stamp displayed is incorrect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to change the timezone in the `php.ini` configuration file, and then restart the apache service.
You should have `php.ini` somewhere  inside your WAMP installation folder.

**EDIT:** You might have the php.ini file inside the folder:

```
/wamp/bin/php/phpX.X.X
```

where phpX.X.X is your php version.

Look for the "date.timezone" line and change it to something like this:

```
date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

You can find the supported timezones here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

More technical information is available here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

The .htaccess file has a local range, normally to the folder and sub-folders where the file is created. Changing the php.ini file makes the changes global to your PHP installation.

Comment: I edited php.ini as you said and then "Restarted all services" and it didn't help but "Stopping all services" and then "Starting all Services" helped.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to editing the /wamp/bin/php/phpX.X.X/php.ini you would need to make the same changes on Apache side too. Which is on /wamp/bin/apache/ApacheX.X.X/bin/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I'm using wampserver 3.0 and having the same issue even after changing *date.timezone* for both files:

- *\bin\php\php5.6.15\phpForApache.ini*
- *\bin\php\php5.6.15\php.ini*

After the changes the server was stopped/started, also tried using the restart button.  Result are the following:

- Date is ok (as before) but time is still off by exactly 50 minutes.
- Apache access log shows correct time offset at +8 hours
- Php error log shows correct time zone

[image]

Comment: hmm ... this doesn't look like a solution, is it?

Comment: No it's not, but the site suggests "Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer."