# How to change the time in apache server so it matches the computer's time (PHP)?

Tags: php, apache

In my particular case, both the server and the client are the same computer, I'm on localhost. When i echo out the date from the date() function, it displays a totally wrong value, a 11 hours earlier time. I also tried gmdate(), but it displays the date in AM not PM. Is there any way to change the apache server time, so everytime I get it in php, it displays the same as the time on my computer?

EDIT: Sorry for the late edit. I have already set the timezone in the php.ini but it still doesn't work. And I'm sure that my timezone is correct, since I got it from the manual and checked from phpinfo().

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596083/apache-time-stamp-incorrect/8596163#8596163

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Comment: @TomS I have already done that, but it still doesn't work!!

Comment: you can try to chanage time in php by date_default_timezone_set or you can also change the timezone in your php.ini file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you are looking for: `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )`

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

You can also set this in your php.ini config.

Comment: good answer, only problem with date_default_timezone_set is it's a function, so if the OP is running software he didn't write he would have to add it to every piece of software he's running whereas setting it in the php.ini such as in my answer, that's the only place he should have to change the setting.

Comment: It all depends on what you're writing software for -- if you're writing software for portability, having the ability to set this in the code may be a desirable trait.

Comment: Yes Andy that's correct.  However, if you want your server on a localhost to be the same as your local time, setting it in the php.ini is optimal.  Then creating the ability to change it in the program (if its a program you are writing) is a secondary to provide the portability in that respect.

Comment: I chose this as the best answer because it worked indeed, but only after I restarted my computer the other day (today). It wouldn't work even after apache restart though, but now it's fine. Thanks.

Comment: Want to repeat and even more stress menislici comment above that you need to REBOOT WHOLE SERVER to make changes take effect. Just simple Apache 2 restart (either throught apache2ctl or systectl) is not enough. I doubted at first, but as insane as it sounds reboot finally saved my day.

Answer (score 17):

Open the php.ini under /etc/php.ini .

Uncomment this line and add your continent and the main city. Here is an example which works for Germany (Deutschland).

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```

See the website http://php.net/manual/de/timezones.php for all timezones in German.

Save the file php.ini. And restart the apache.
Mageia LINUX uses this:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Comment: Scroll through the entire `php.ini` and make this change at all `date.timezone = `

Answer (score 10):

You need to do this in your php.ini file.  I am on windows and run WAMP so my php.ini location is at: c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/bin/

You then open that file and the default is set to: `date.timezone = UTC` You would change this value for whatever timezone you want...

For a full list of timezones supported, you can visit: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed in the `php.ini`:

- If using xampp, open `xampp/php/php.ini`.
- Look for the line `date.timezone=Europe/Berlin` and change it to your timezone.
  In my case I changed to `date.timezone=Africa/Nairobi`.
- Save and restart apache.