# Date function displaying wrong date

Tags: php

This is my code for displaying today's current date:

```
$date = date('m/d/Y'); 
echo"(".$date.")";
```

In return my output is:

```
(08/14/2013)
```

Why isn't the date displaying today's actual date which is `8/13/2013`?

Comment: Is this ran locally on your machine?

Comment: What date does your server think it is?

Comment: Maybe because you or your server are in a different country/continent? No, I'm not being sarcastic.

Comment: My actual date on my laptop is 8/13/2013 at this very moment. By locally, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I am using Wampserver as well.

Comment: @JoseFuentes Are you running your own web server, or is this on a hosted web site elsewhere?

Comment: @JoseFuentes Check your computer's clock then. Strangest thing I've seen if it's not the case.

Comment: @JoseFuentes I ran your script and got (08/13/2013). My server is 500 miles away, but in the same timezone.

Comment: This is currently running on my own web server. And it is strange because if i use the Date(NOW()) function when retrieving events from my database, it displays it for today's date.

Comment: @JoseFuentes what if you tried `echo $date;` instead of `echo"(".$date.")";` ?

Comment: @JoseFuentes See this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/8648408/1415724 Question itself is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648369/how-to-change-the-time-in-apache-server-so-it-matches-the-computers-time-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time and dates in PHP are dependent on a few things.

1. What the date and time are on the machine PHP is running on
2. The timezone which is set as default either in code or in the php.ini file.

   date.timezone="America/New_York"

or

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

With one of these set to another time zone like GMT or something you could be off as by a very large offset.

Comment: Ok i entered the code you provided: before i echoed

Comment: I meant to say I entered your code before I echoed the date and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging with:

```
$date=date('m/d/Y e O');
echo $date;
```

That way you can see timezone information for the date being displayed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: It displays "UTC +0000"

Comment: Then it is correct. The date is the 14th in already, in UTC.

Comment: And is that the timezone that you're in? If not then that explains the difference in date. You can then use stanlest's answer to set the default timezone or just use php's date_add() function to correct the offset yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're running your own webserver you can set the timezone in the php.ini -  http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your problem is but I would set the timezone before getting date

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
```

[This Page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) tells you what timezones are available