# How to display the current date

Tags: php

I hope anyone will help me with this. I just want to display the current date in here. But my code is not working, any idea? Thank you in advance though. :)

[image of the problem. click this to view. it must "october 2, not 3."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJaO5.png)

Here's my code.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"><?php print date('F j, Y l'); ?></div>
```

Comment: The problem isn't your code. The problem probably is the set time(zone) of the server.

Comment: I think my time here in my laptop is correct. It is October 2, but the display is October 3. :(

Comment: What `timezone_offset_get()` returns?

Comment: @DanielleClaudeD.Macarayan I'm not referring to your laptop. I'm referring to your php server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the time in apache server so it matches the computer's time (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648369/how-to-change-the-time-in-apache-server-so-it-matches-the-computers-time-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on first line of your code

```
date_default_timezone_set("your country");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php